# Can we upload an MP3 file in Sanity.io?

Tags: file, audio, upload, sanity

I am building a podcast web app for that I wish to use Sanity. I know for videos I can utilize the `mux` plugin but I don't find any standard examples for working with just audio files.

If it is possible to upload MP3 in sanity, how can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

```
     defineField({
          name: 'audio',
          title: 'Audio',
          type: 'file',
          options: {accept: 'audio/*'},
        }),
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?